# Spring MVC - Get reference data from database on server startup

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, drop-down-menu

After reading lot of posts i am planning to use below approach to pull reference data from database (code not tested yet).

```
    @Override
    protected Map referenceData(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

        //Data referencing for country list box
        Map referenceData = new HashMap();
        referenceData.put("countryList", articleService.getCountryList());

        //Data referencing for skills list box
        Map<String,String> javaSkill = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
        referenceData.put("skillsList", articleService.getSkillsList());

        return referenceData;
    }
```

Reference data table is as below

```
id  key     value               type
-----------------------------------------
1   1       United States       countries
2   2       India               countries
3   3       United Kingdom      countries
4   4       China               countries
5   1       Java                skills
6   2       Spring              skills
7   3       Hibernate           skills
8   4       SQL                 skills
```

I have got two questions,

1. This is a static reference data (i wont change it for months), so I dont want to hit database for every request and data should be loaded on server startup instead. How to do this?
2. Is this the correct approach or i am complately wrong in understanding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I would say it's a correct approach. You should put countries in their own table, and skills in their own table.

First because additional column will inevitably appear for countries, which don't make any sense for skills (or vice-versa).

And second because you will want to reference countries or skills from other tables in your database (and other entities in your object model). So you'll want to have foreign keys from addresses to countries, for example, and you wouldn't want an address to reference a skill rather than a country. And you'll want a ManyToOne association from Address to Country, and not from Address to ReferenceTable.

I have the feeling that you're pre-optimizing. Such reference tables are small, and the database will hold everything in memory. So querying them, even if you do it frequently, will be extreely fast.

If you want to avoid those queries completely, then you could simply use the second-level cache of hibernate, which will make everything transparent (i.e. you will keep programming as usual, and Hibernate will go to its cache instead of going to the database). This will bring additional advantages, such as being able to actually update information in those tables without getting stale values for too long (or without getting stale values at all).

Comment: thanks for your inputs JB. specifically about foreign keys part. Although i understood why i've to keep countries and skills tables separate, I still have a question about loading reference data on server startup. I am sure this must be done in lot of applications for loading static reference data. I am trying to find out what is the most common approach in taken in this schenario (i am still googling it after the post)

Comment: The common approach is to use the second-level cache. And then either wait for the first requests to be executed and load the cache lazily, or execute fake queries and loops at startup just to populate the cache immediately. I would simply do it lazily, and only take additional measures if you prove that this causes a performance problem.

Comment: Well, if a table needs to be super modular and have foreign key relations, it's no longer a `reference` data, and you should use proper ORM to access it.

Comment: thanks JB but i still have got a question and posting on a new thread. Hope you can advice... link belolw  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669502/spring-mvc-loading-reference-data-from-second-level-cache

Answer (score 2):

I would create an `Enum` with `key` and `value` constructor for `Country` and another one for `Skill`. It is definitely more error-prone, but if you build them carefully, the performance improvement will be worth it. See code below:

```
public enum Country {
    UNITED_STATES(1, "United States"), INDIA(2, "India"), UNITED_KINGDOM(1, "United Kingdom"), CHINA(4, "China");  

    private int key;
    private String value;

    Country (int key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

So you never need to go the database to get them, and with enums you can do all kind of things, enumeration, accessing reference properties easily, uniform and consistent access to reference data across your app, instead of lumping them in a map.

Comment: I second this approach. Better to keep static reference data, like this, in Enum for performance tuning.